# How can I use RSpec to test my model's interaction with external services

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, mocking, rspec

I have a method in a model that interacts with an external video encoding service (Zencoder). It uses the zencoder_rb gem. https://github.com/zencoder/zencoder-rb

```
class EncodingRequest
  def check_encoding_status
    response = Zencoder::Job.details(self.request_id)
    if response.success?
      # do something
    else
      # do something else
    end
  end
end
```

The Zencoder::Job#details method makes a call to the Zencoder web service to find out if the video encoding is complete.

The question is how can I hijack the Zencoder::Job#details method so when it is called by check_encoding_status it will return an object that I can craft. The plan is to make that object respond to #success? in whatever way makes sense for my test.

So here's how I'd like the spec to look

```
it "should mark the encoding as failed if there was an error in Zencoder" do
  dummy_response = Zencoder::Response.new(:body => {:state => "finished"}, :code => 200)
  # code that will force Zencoder::Job#details to return this dummy_response

  @encoding = EncodingRequest.new(:source_asset => @final_large, :target_asset => @final_small)
  @encoding.check_encoding_status
  @encoding.status.should eql "success"
end
```

I am currently using rspec 2.5.
I read a bit about mocks and stubs, but I am not sure it's possible to use them in this scenario.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Zencoder::Job.stub_chain(:details, :success).and_return(true)
```